# Python naming conventions for modules in subpackages

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8

I'm creating a python package which will be used by a small end user group of approx. 20 people. An even smaller developer team of 3 people will be contributing to the package.

My package contains multiple subpackages. I don't want the end users to access any of the utility functions from the subpackage. How do I name the subpackages and modules within these subpackages?

- Start the module name within the subpackage with an underscore? e.g. _mymodule.py
- Start the subpackage name with an underscore? e.g. _mypackage
- Both?

My intent is to communicate to the end user, that these subpackages are not designed for them. However, the functions might be required as utility functions from other subpackages and are therefore not really "private".

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced this is necessary. Just hiding stuff in a subpackage is often enough to obscure it from casual users.

Comment:  Agreed. Provide the functions the user is supposed to interact with in the top module, and document it extensively so it's clear how users are supposed to use the module. Anything that's not documented and not obviously directly useful is typically understood to be internal implementation details.

Comment: If users will want to use undocumented features they will be able to do it anyway because of dynamic nature of python. There are no truly private "things", so just use common used way(pep8) - naming with one underscore to indicate that thing is not public. Both options from your example are acceptable if you want to mark things protected

Comment: Thanks for the answers. However, putting everything in the top module won't be practicable due to the large number of different methods. I agree with your suggestion for smaller packages with limited functionality.

Comment: After a little further research I took inspiration from the pandas github repository. (e.g. the io subpackage) The approach is difficult to generalize and it looks like a case to case decision. But the result feels right: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/tree/master/pandas/io

Comment: FWIW, in `numpy` we wish we had used `_`, because we have who knows how many users that are now relying on what were supposed to be implementation details. If you don't want users to use your stuff, at least the blame is on them when their code stops working if the private modules start with `_`.

Answer (score -2):

The method inside the class should be declared with prefix __(double underscore). When the methods are prefixed with __, they are considered as private. Please check below code,

class Base:

```
# Declaring public method 
def fun(self): 
    print("Public method") 

# Declaring private method 
def __fun(self): 
    print("Private method")
```

In this class, method __fun cannot be accessed by below object,
obj1 = Base()
obj1.__fun()

Line obj1.__fun() will raise AttributeError.

Comment: OP is asking about module naming, not methods.

Comment: ..and it's not really "private". You could still access the method as `obj1._Base__fun()`.

Comment: Python has no privacy model like other languages do, only naming conventions and [class name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers). Their use is in *avoiding name collisions with subclasses*, not encapsulation. Most of all, this only applies to names **in a class definition**, not to *module names*, which is what the question is about.